# Ler strings em java dentro de uma estrutura de repetição while ou do-while

Tags: java, string, buffer

Como faço para ler strings em java dentro de uma estrutura de repetição while ou do-while? sem dá erro e não lê

Código:

```
package listas;

import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Listas {
    //declaração de Variáveis
    static List lista = new ArrayList();
    static Scanner ler = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {            
            System.out.println("0-Sair");
            System.out.println("1-Cadastrar");
            System.out.println("2-Listar");
            System.out.println("3-Remover");
            char op = (char) ler.nextByte();
            switch (op) {
                case 0 : exit(0);break;
                case 1 : cadastrar(); break;
                case 2 : break;
                case 3 : break;
                default : {
                    System.out.println("Opção Inválida!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void cadastrar () {
        System.out.print("Digite: ");
        String str = new String ();
        str = ler.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Que erro? Edite a pergunta explicando .

Comment: `char op = (char) ler.nextByte();` isto não faz o que espera que faça, e naturalmente não é a forma correta de ler um `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
package listas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Listas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {            
            System.out.println("0-Sair");
            System.out.println("1-Cadastrar");
            System.out.println("2-Listar");
            System.out.println("3-Remover");
            String op = ler.nextLine().trim();
            switch (op) {
                case "0":
                    return;
                case "1":
                    cadastrar();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    break;
                case "3":
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opção Inválida!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void cadastrar() {
        System.out.print("Digite: ");
        String str = ler.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Lembre que a partir do Java 7, `String`s podem ser usadas em `switch`es.

Além disso, evite usar o `System.exit`. Isso é uma má prática de programação.

O `ler.nextByte()` não faz o que você espera. Por isso use o `ler.nextLine()`.

Comment: Qual a alternativa ao `System.exit`?

Comment: @Sorack Usar `return` dentro do `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de

```
Scanner ler = new Scanner (System.in);

// ...

char op = (char) ler.nextByte();
```

você poderia usar

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

// ...

String s = br.readLine();
```

.

Mais detalhes e opções de implementação em: [Java: How to get input from System.console()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4645193/1022567)